# Capybara tests fail using selenium webdriver

Tags: ruby-on-rails, selenium-webdriver, rspec, capybara, spree

I am trying to test a spree extension. Some of the tests are feature tests. These tests use selenium-webdriver as javascript driver. 
Here is my gemspec for the extension.

*spree_extension.gemspec*

---

```
# Runtime
s.add_dependency 'spree_core', '>= 3.2', '< 3.6'
s.add_dependency 'spree_sample', '>= 3.2', '< 3.6'
# Development
s.add_development_dependency 'appraisal'
s.add_development_dependency 'shoulda-matchers',   '~> 3.1.1'
s.add_development_dependency 'factory_bot',       '~> 4.8.2'
s.add_development_dependency 'coffee-rails',       '~> 4.2.1'
s.add_development_dependency 'database_cleaner',   '~> 1.5.3'
s.add_development_dependency 'sqlite3',            '~> 1.3.11'
s.add_development_dependency 'capybara',           '~> 2.7.1'
s.add_development_dependency 'selenium-webdriver', '~> 2.53.0'
s.add_development_dependency 'launchy',            '~> 2.4.3'
s.add_development_dependency 'rspec-rails',        '~> 3.7'
```

*spec_helper.rb*

---

```
# Configure Rails Environment
ENV['RAILS_ENV'] = 'test'

require File.expand_path('../dummy/config/environment.rb',  __FILE__)

require 'rspec/rails'
require 'capybara/rspec'
require 'database_cleaner'
require 'factory_bot'
FactoryBot.find_definitions
require 'ffaker'
require 'paperclip/matchers'
require 'shoulda/matchers'

# Requires supporting ruby files with custom matchers and macros, etc,
# in spec/support/ and its subdirectories.
Dir[File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), 'support/**/*.rb')].each { |f| require f }

# Requires factories defined in spree_core
require 'spree/testing_support/factories'
require 'spree/testing_support/controller_requests'
require 'spree/testing_support/authorization_helpers'
require 'spree/testing_support/capybara_ext'
require 'spree/testing_support/url_helpers'

RSpec.configure do |config|
config.include FactoryBot::Syntax::Methods
config.include Paperclip::Shoulda::Matchers

# == URL Helpers
#
# Allows access to Spree's routes in specs:
#
# visit spree.admin_path
# current_path.should eql(spree.products_path)
config.include Spree::TestingSupport::UrlHelpers
config.extend Spree::TestingSupport::AuthorizationHelpers::Request, type: :feature
config.include Spree::TestingSupport::ControllerRequests, type: :controller

# == Mock Framework
#
# If you prefer to use mocha, flexmock or RR, uncomment the appropriate line:
#
# config.mock_with :mocha
# config.mock_with :flexmock
# config.mock_with :rr
config.mock_with :rspec
config.color = true

# Remove this line if you're not using ActiveRecord or ActiveRecord fixtures
config.fixture_path = File.join( File.dirname(__FILE__), 'spec/fixtures')

# Capybara javascript drivers require transactional fixtures set to false, and we use DatabaseCleaner
# to cleanup after each test instead.  Without transactional fixtures set to false the records created
# to setup a test will be unavailable to the browser, which runs under a seperate server instance.
config.use_transactional_fixtures = false

config.before :each do |example|
  if example.metadata[:js]
    DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :truncation
  else
    DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :transaction
  end
  DatabaseCleaner.start
end

config.after :each do
  DatabaseCleaner.clean
end

config.fail_fast = ENV['FAIL_FAST'] || false

# rspec-rails 3 will no longer automatically infer an example group's spec type
# from the file location. You can explicitly opt-in to the feature using this
# config option.
# To explicitly tag specs without using automatic inference, set the `:type`
# metadata manually:
#
#     describe ThingsController, :type => :controller do
#       # Equivalent to being in spec/controllers
#     end
config.infer_spec_type_from_file_location!
end

Shoulda::Matchers.configure do |config|
  config.integrate do |with|
    # Choose a test framework:
    with.test_framework :rspec

    # Or, choose the following (which implies all of the above):
    with.library :rails
  end
end
```

---

I am using Firefox v45.0. The problem is that although the Firefox window opens and tests run, but the feature tests which interact with javascript (defined in the extension) are failing.

As an example here is one scenario:

```
scenario "expect to have a disabled add to cart button" do
  visit spree.product_path(product)
  within "div.add-to-cart" do
    expect(page).to have_css('button#add-to-cart-button')
    expect(page.find('button#add-to-cart-button').disabled?).to be_truthy  # <= This test here is failing
  end
end
```

I am disabling the button in the javascript that is defined in this extension, but the test fails because i think my tests are never seeing that.

Does selenium require more setup for javascript?

Comment: Are you specifying ‘js: true’ metadata on an ancestor of the scenario? If not try adding it to the scenario

Comment: @ThomasWalpole Yes I am using js: true like this `feature "Products variant options", js: true do #scenarios end`

Comment: The FF you're using is really old - are you sure it's not raising any JS errors in the browser console? Also, rather than your 2 expectations you should just be writing something like `expect(page).to have_button('add-to-cart-button', disabled: true)` . Note: This all assumes you are actually adding the `disabled` attribute to the button in order to disable it, not just adding a class that styles it to look disabled.

Answer (score 0):

Okay so I figured out what was wrong. The generators were not being run when making the dummy app. The generators in the lib directory have to be  placed in the install directory. 
So the directory structure has to be

```
lib
 -> generators
   -> *extension_name*
     -> install
       -> install_generator.rb
```

That is when the dummy app that is made for testing will see the generators to run.